# Amazon S3 AWS Rest API Version 2 or Vesion 4

Tags: amazon, aws, amazone-rest-api-version

I want to create a bucket in S3 Amazon using Rest API and also using version 2.

1) I want to know which parameters I need to include and which parameter I need to include in the creation of signature.

2) Do I need to put "Host" parameter in header and also include in signature string. what should be the value of host.

3)What should be the endpoint.

4) I think end points should not be start with bucket name as bucket name is dynamic and we have to define Url in remote site setting and it would be static.

5) What would be the date format x-am-date parameter and  Date parameter.

It would be great if some one provide me signature create code or example with code as I followed all the instruction describe by S3 documentation but didn't success.

Comment: I am doing integration with s3 in apex so, I need help as I've stucked so why you all put my question on hold.

Comment: See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Your question appears to be all about the remote API (S3) not techniques in Apex to invoke that API. So you will get more help from a community that specializes in S3. For example, there are 7695 questions and answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3. If you then have a problem with how to invoke the API from Apex, post that here.